# MYSQL trigger after insert => insert into second table => before insert trigger not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I got this datebase structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `usr_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usr_mail` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usr_creationdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usr_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_activation` (
  `usract_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usr_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `usract_key` text NOT NULL,
  `usract_used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usract_creationdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `usract_usagedate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `usract_expiredate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


CREATE TRIGGER `USER_INSERT_ADD_ACTIVATION` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO user_activation (usr_id, usract_key)
 VALUES (NEW.usr_id, UUID());


CREATE TRIGGER `USRACT_INSER_SET_EXPIREDATA` BEFORE INSERT ON `user_activation`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 SET NEW.usract_expiredate = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

When I insert data into the table `user_activation` my `user_activation.usract_expiredate` gets updated to the next day.
If I insert data into the table `user` a row is insert into `user_activation` but `user_activation.usract_expiredate` will not get set to the next day.
Seems like the second trigger is not being executed.

Am I doing something wrong with the triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need only one trigger to achieve this.

```
DROP TRIGGER `USRACT_INSER_SET_EXPIREDATA`;
DROP TRIGGER `USER_INSERT_ADD_ACTIVATION`;

CREATE TRIGGER `USER_INSERT_ADD_ACTIVATION` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 INSERT INTO user_activation (usr_id, usract_key,usract_expiredate)
 VALUES (NEW.usr_id, UUID(),DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Comment: I know that i could workaround my problem with seting the time in the other trigger. But as i plan to have more tables that use the `user_activation` table, I dont like the idea that i have to write it into all the triggers that i setup. In general the second trigger should get called. I just would like to know why it is not called.

Comment: your trigger (the one I suggested that you delete) is in fact getting called. but it's value is not being used because you probably h ave some other code or trigger that overrides it.

Comment: Also be aware that having multiple triggers being fired for each insert is going to slow down those inserts.

Comment: Apparently the `datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the column making the value change again from `NOW + 1 DAY` to the `NOW` after the trigger is called.

Comment: glad it's sorted. All the best with your project